# The student discount version of Windows 7 is labeled as "upgrade"; could I do a clean install on a new PC?

Tags: windows-7, build

I am building my own PC, and I am interested in getting Windows 7 (64 bit) with a student discount. On the [Microsoft site](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/pd/productID.216644200?WT.mc_id=EducationSite_academicsavings), it is labeled as an upgrade; does that mean I can't just purchase it and install on my brand new PC? And if I do download it on my current computer running Vista (but NOT install it on my current PC), could I use a flash drive or hard drive to install on my new PC?

I have looked around on the Web and here on SU and have some different answers, but I want to be sure before purchasing. Thanks!

Comment: If you're in college (you mention a student discout), they usually have a place where you can get your OS upgraded / reinstalled. Granted, school isn't in at the moment, at least where I'm at.

Comment: Why not call [1-800-RU-LEGIT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/piracy/default.aspx) and ask Microsoft? They'll know. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have Windows (XP or newer) installed to upgrade. Since the CD doesn't know if you've upgraded your computer or not, I would say you could use it on other computers as well. If you have a 32-bit system, however, and want 64-bit, that requires a reinstall of Windows.

Look under the 'Before You Buy' tab on the page you posted.